# Tkinter progress bar with Excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

We have a Pyxll app (Excel app written in python) that makes a bunch of requests to get data when the workbook is opened. We would like to display a loading bar to the user while the requests are being made and update the loading bar after each request returns.

I'm trying to use Tkinter to do this, but have run into issues. I can get a progress bar to pop up, but it blocks Excel from running until you close the window for the progress bar. I can't put it in a different thread because I want to be able to update the progress based on when the HTTP requests return. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code so far. I have made a basic loading bar class:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class OrderingProgressBar(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # progress goes from 0-100 (for percentage)
        self.progress = 0
        self.max_progress = 100

        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate", maximum=self.max_progress)
        self.progress_bar.pack()
```

And then I have a macro that gets called to launch the app and start making requests.

```
def launch_ordering_terminal(ribbon):
    """Launch all of the apps required for the Ordering Terminal"""
    ordering_progress_bar = OrderingProgressBar()
    ordering_progress_bar.mainloop()

    excel_utils.turn_off_excel_updates(xl_app())
    launch_allocation_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_si_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_accounting_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_reports_builder(terminal_mode)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    excel_utils.turn_on_excel_updates(xl_app())
```

With this code, when I call the macro a loading bar pops up, but block Excel. If I close the window it continues. If I move the `mainloop` call to the end of `launch_ordering_terminal`, then the entire terminal loads, and then it pops up the loading bar. I can't get them to work at the same time.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a GUI is a full time job that requires an endless loop, called the "mainloop". If you want to do something else in the meantime, you need to add it to the mainloop, or do it in a different thread. In your case I think a new thread would be easiest. Tkinter runs best in the main thread, so put your code in a child thread.

As a totally untested guess:

```
from threading import Thread

def do_stuff(ordering_progress_bar):
    excel_utils.turn_off_excel_updates(xl_app())
    launch_allocation_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_si_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_accounting_app(manager_id)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    launch_reports_builder(terminal_mode)
    ordering_progress_bar.progress_bar.step(25)
    excel_utils.turn_on_excel_updates(xl_app())
    ordering_progress_bar.quit() # kill the GUI

def launch_ordering_terminal(ribbon):
    """Launch all of the apps required for the Ordering Terminal"""
    ordering_progress_bar = OrderingProgressBar()
    t = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(ordering_progress_bar,))
    t.start()
    ordering_progress_bar.mainloop()
```